# Keep mic on android speech to text

Tags: android, speech-to-text

i want to mic on when i click on mic button and when again i click on mic button then it turn off. 
i have a code kindly guide me how i keep mic on.
for example when i click mic button it start listening and when i click on mic again then it stop listening.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
    private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
    private ImageButton mSpeakBtn;

    private String[] myWords = {"start","stop","deactivate","activate","scan"};
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    boolean isStart;
    String strings;
    String start="start";
    String stop="stop";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
        mSpeakBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mVoiceInputTv.setText("");
                startVoiceInput();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startVoiceInput() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, Please Speak somethings");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                    ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    TextView n=new TextView(this);
                    if  (((result.get(0).toLowerCase()).contains(start))&&result.get(0).contains(stop)) {
                      strings = getBetweenStrings(result.get(0), start, stop);
                        mVoiceInputTv.setText("" + strings);
                    }
                        Log.d("action","String "+strings+ "  result "+result.get(0)+" "+result.get(0).equals(myWords[0].toLowerCase()));
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    public static String getBetweenStrings(
            String text,
            String textFrom,
            String textTo) {

        String result = "";
        result = text.substring(text.indexOf(textFrom) + textFrom.length(), text.length());
        result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf(textTo));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: i did not want to record.
i want mic on always when i click on min and when click again mic should off

Comment: i am studying alot about my given question but i cant found any solution.
but i have an idea in mind. can we do it as"when the application is on and mic also on and when the application is turned off mic also turned off"??
any one have idea about it?? if have then please guide me